# What is the meaning of 'v.1.0' in HTTP requests in the Dapr API?

Tags: dapr

In the Dapr API, most HTTP requests are in the format `http://localhost:<daprPort>/v1.0/...`.
What does "v1.0" means? And when will I need to change it to another value?

Comment: I do think it means that they are at version "1.0", and it will change when they release a new version?

Comment: Just found the page where they explain when it is going to change: https://docs.dapr.io/operations/support/support-versioning/

Comment: So, is it the version of Dapr HTTP API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the HTTP API version.

It will change when a new feature is released and you decide to use the new version.

In [Dapr Community Call 13](https://youtu.be/ysklxm81MTs?t=2143) this information is explicitly stated.

You can find more about [in the documentation](https://docs.dapr.io/operations/support/support-versioning/#dapr-http-api).

Thanks to [@Luuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/724039) for showing this documentation link.